# Specifying origin path in Cloudfront without a redirect

Tags: dns, github-pages, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to host a github pages site on Cloudfront.

The problem is, the github repo is at `username.github.io/repo` rather than `username.github.io`.

If I specify `username.github.io` as the origin domain, and `/repo` as the origin path, then going to `id.cloudfront.net` redirects you fully to `username.github.io/repo` which is not what I want. I want it to stay at `id.cloudfront.net` (or `mydomain.com` aliased to `id.cloudfront.net`) and display the content of the github site, without redirecting to it.

Removing the origin path fixes this issue and loads the content from `username.github.io`, but I need the content from `username.github.io/repo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue - the github pages site has a 'force https' setting - which means it forces a redirect to `https://username.github.io/repo` if accessed thru http.

I had my origin protocol set to http in cloudfront (default) which was triggering this redirect. Setting it to https fixed the issue.